# get Original Attribute for Eloquent Model Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have `Foo` Attribute that use `getFooAttribute` method to format it before display but in some places, I need original attribute for it. So how can I do it?

Comment: If you want to get it's original value you will have to remove your get mutator.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Inurosen I need mutator in some places

Answer (score 44):

Getting the original value of a particular attribute from v4.2 onwards:

`$originalFoo = $model->getOriginal('foo');`

Comment: getOriginal() method is intended to be used to get original value of an attribute loaded from the database. It will only work in scenarios where this value doesn't change. It won't work as the OP expected if this value gets modified. Quick example: 1) assume $model gets loaded from the DB and the value of $model->getOriginal('foo') is "foo". 2) Change value of the attribute: $model->foo = "bar"; 3) $model->getOriginal('foo') will return "foo" instead of "bar".

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo That is why you should use the setter `$model->setFoo("bar")` instead. That preserves the `$original` array and is a good practice overall.

Answer (score 21):

If you want to use **mutator** in the majority of the code but sometimes would like to access the original value, you can do it by fetching all attributes using **getAttributes()** method of your model and then fetching the value from there, e.g.:

```
$originalFoo = $model->getAttributes()['foo'];
```

Answer (score 17):

If you want the raw field straight out of database skipping the mutator then

```
$mode->getRawOriginal('attribute')
```

is the way to go. `$model->getOriginal()` will give you the mutator value **not** the raw data you want.

see https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_getRawOriginal

Answer (score 7):

for laravel 5 we can also use:

```
$model->getOriginal('foo')
```

credits to @bower

Answer (score 7):

## Laravel 7 and Symfony 5 respectively

```php
$model->getRawOriginal()
```

> #### The getOriginal Method
>
> Likelihood Of Impact: Low
>
> The `$model->getOriginal()` method will now respect any casts and mutators defined on the model. Previously, this method returned the uncast, raw attributes. If you would like to continue retrieving the raw, uncast values, you may use the `getRawOriginal` method instead.

- *Reference A: [Upgrade Guide: Upgrading To Laravel 7.0 From 6.x](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/upgrade#symfony-5-related-upgrades)*
- *Reference B: [Laravel 7.x Eloquent API](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.html#method_getRawOriginal)*

Answer (score 6):

I am using 5.3 and for this I use `$model->getOriginal()['foo']`

Comment: It's worth noting that if you wish to obtain the original value of a particular attribute, you can just pass a key into `getOriginal`. e.g. `$model->getOriginal('foo')`

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me

```
$newProduct = $product[0]->getRawOriginal();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually looks all above are correct, just see if this is in array key [0]
for example:

```
$originalFoo = $model[0]->getRawOriginal('foo');
```

Answer (score -2):

Something that might be worth mentioning as well is that the Laravel model class overwrites the magic methods for `__set` and `__get`, so you can also retrieve the `original` attribute dynamically i.e. `$model->original`.

See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php